# Android studio 3.4 can not save my color scheme ，

Tags: android-studio

In previous version of Android studio 3.4, color scheme can be saved and used when it is opened. Now every time Android studio is opened, color scheme becomes the default setting,  I should change my custom color shceme perference this manually.

[image]

Comment: I upgrate to Android studio 3.5 , and the problem solve.

Comment: I upgrate to Android studio 3.5 , and the problem solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  upgrate to Android studio 3.5 , and the problem solve.